# How to Find Out Where a File is Being Required?

Tags: helm, require

Using benchmark-init, I see that helm files (helm-elisp, helm-mode, helm, etc.) are being required, but I don't have "(require 'helm)" or "(require 'helm-config)" or "(helm-mode 1)" anywhere in my init file. I'm using use-package, and all helm-related packages are deferred, including helm. Is there some direct way I can figure out where helm is being required from? I also want to find out where semantic is being required from.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by benchmark-init, you should also put `(benchmark-init/show-durations-tree)` (or similar) at the end of your `init.el`, instead of running it with `M-x` (if it is `helm-M-x`, many helm-* requires might be made in a single `helm-M-x`).  I guess benchmark-init doesn't know (and doesn't care) when Emacs initialization is finished.

Comment: It does have a `(benchmark-init/deactivate)`. I had just made the mistake of not uncommenting it; thanks! That fixes the helm part of my problem.

Comment: Your solution is better, I am unfamiliar with benchmark-init (and its doc seems not good).  So now, you know helm is being required when you first use helm's function and at the time if benchmark-init is not deactivated, it will also display requiring info of helm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any standard way of doing this. However, you can fairly simply advice `require` so that it keeps trace of who calls it.

```lisp
(defvar my/require-tree nil)
(defun require--advice (orig-fun feature &rest args)
  (setq my/require-tree
    (append my/require-tree
        (list (let ((my/require-tree (list feature)))
            (apply orig-fun feature args)
            my/require-tree)))))
(advice-add 'require :around 'require--advice)
```

If you put this at the beginning of your init file, you should at the end get something like this in the `my/require-tree` variable:

```lisp
((org
  (calendar
   (cal-menu
    (calendar)))
  (find-func)
  (format-spec)
  (org-macs)
  (org-compat
   (org-macs))
  (ob-emacs-lisp
   (ob
    (org-macs)
    (org-compat)
    (ob-eval
     (org-macs))
    (ob-core
     (ob-eval)
     (org-macs)
     (org-compat))
    (ob-comint
     (ob-core)
     (org-compat)
     (comint))
    (ob-exp
     (ob-core))))
  ;;...
  )
 (tramp
  ;;...
  ))
```

**NB:** You can use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`my/require-tree`<kbd>RET</kbd> to see the contents of the variable in a nicely formatted way.

Comment: Thanks! This gives a somewhat better overview than benchmark/init. However, there are still some things at the top level that I'm confused about. For example, paredit appears at the top level (and the only package I use that requires paredit is autoloaded). I don't use linum either, but it is being required. I'm also curious as to where some libraries like f.el are first being loaded.